# can't make a connection to the Mysql server, there is no root password set

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

HI guys I can't make a connection to the server whenever trying to create a new database even though I have MySQL server runnig, a connection on Workbench made and MySQL is running in default 3306 port. This is all I have found from looking online any input on this will be greatly appreciated I am running out of time. I also was not asked to set up a password while installing MySQL, whenevr I try to set up one in Mysql I get password not long enough error even though the one I have put in is longer than 8 characters, with other char combinations, the screen starts loading and being asked to set up password again. Other answers I have found on stack overflow is not helping me either

Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local

Answer (score 0):

for me downloading through homebrew worked fantastic and I have macbook air and downloading in the traditional way from MySQL website was not working even though I was using every single solution I found on internet. If you are trying to download and install MySQL and Workbench on Mac just do it through homebrew , it will be much faster and better